# Draw graph with multiple tables in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Is there an easy way to add multiple HTML tables into the same Highcharts graph? I have multiple tables in HTML displayed on my page, and would also like to display them in the same Highcharts graph to compare them to each other.

**I was thinking something like this:**

```
data: {
           table: document.getElementById('table1'),
           table: document.getElementById('table2')
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: We solved this by rolling our own series from each table and columns. Method depends on your table structure.

Comment: You an also look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3wc9tyh7/6/

Comment: I took a look at the example, @GrzegorzBlachliński, and this helped me get two graphs. However, I could not seem to get a third graph added. Do you have a tips on how to get the third?

Comment: Here you can see an example with adding the third table http://jsfiddle.net/3wc9tyh7/8/